# How do I include the main js bundle in my expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

Not sure if I'm missing something very obvious but I'm trying to build and test my app on a real device without running the Metro Bundler locally or having the app access the js bundle from a server. I want the app to work offline with the js bundle included.

My Google-Fu has failed me and I can only find outdate expo commands of `expo publish`. I was able to do it by specifying the command `npx expo run:android --variant release`, but I'm trying to upload the `.aab` that `eas build` produces to the play store for internal testing and when I do the app crashes immediately.

P.S.: My EAS command is `eas build --profile production --platform android --local`